# How to do dimensionality reduction with dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I want to perform a dimensionality reduction on my dask dataframe as it has 25088 features.
I want to extract 90-95% of information or the top 4000-5000 data features from my dataframe.
The data has to be extracted on the basis of "selling_price" information which is available in the dataframe only.

The view of the dataframe is:

```
image_features_df.head(3)
   feat1   feat2   feat3  ...  feat25087    feat25088   fid   selling_price
0   0.0    0.0     0.0    ...   0.0          0.0         2       269.00
4   0.3    0.1     0.0    ...   0.0          0.8         26      1720.00    
6   0.8    0.0     0.0    ...   0.0          0.1         50      18145.25
```

here only first 25088 features has to be used for dimentionality reduction.
I want the output which has reduced dimensions so that I can train a model on top.

**EDIT:**

The data frame is 100 000 rows and 25 088 columns so please tell a solution that doesn't give a memory error.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume Principal Component Analysis is "good enough" for you, as you have not specified the algorithm. Note that scaling of your features is first required.

```
from dask_ml.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
image_features_df = scaler.fit_transform(image_features_df)

pca = PCA(n_components=5000)
pca.fit(image_features_df)
```

Now that you have the fit, you can look for the `90%` (or whatever) explained variance with `pca.explained_variance_ratio_`, i.e.

```
explained_variance = 0.9
cumsum_var = pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum() > explained_variance
idx = cumsum_var.argmax()
print(f'Number of components needed for having at least {explained_variance} is equal to {idx})
```

Comment: I have 64  gb memory available on aws and this solution is still giving me a memory error. The dataframe is 1lakh rows and 25088 columns.

Comment: No wonder, your data likely takes more than 20 GB in memory `100000 * 25088 * 8 bytes`.  Dask provides you distributed processing, but not memory-efficiency. You should look at e.g. incremental PCA https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html , take subset of the data or simply bump AWS VM memory.